# How can I have the pcl includes in my header file without it throwing a "No such file or directory error"?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, point-cloud-library

I want to integrate pcl into some code that I inherited. However, unless I put the pcl includes in the main cpp file the compiler cannot find the library and returns the "No such file or directory" in response to the include files. It seems like a linking issue but I'm not totally sure. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.

I have moved the include statements into the cpp and called libraries within pcl and it works fine. However, I really want to have the includes in the header so I can declare a class pointcloud and the like.
When I move the includes into the header file at all I get the "No such file or directory" error.
If I try to have the include in the cpp file then declare in header I get "'pcl' does not name a type".
I've also tried having the include as #include  but then when the header calls foo.h the first include in foo.h generates the "No such file or directory" error and I get sad again.
In the make file I've included the paths for pcl and eigen. I have also tried compiling with the header and that didn't work.
Below is my Makefile.

```
CAS_DIR := payloads/CAS
CAS_INCLUDES    += -I/usr/local/include  -I. 

SENSOR_INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.8
SENSOR_INCLUDES += -I/usr/local/include/eigen3

LDLIBS      += -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/include 
LDFLAGS     += -lipcx -lmemx -lzmq -lrt -lusb-1.0 -ldl -pthread -lboost_system

sensor.o: $(CAS_DIR)/sensor.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< $(CAS_INCLUDES) $(SENSOR_INCLUDES)

CAS_exec.o: $(CAS_DIR)/CAS_exec.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< $(CAS_INCLUDES)
```

So in conclusion, I really just want to be able to compile with all my pcl includes in the header file or at least the ones that I need to declare class stuff. Right now the compiler doesn't like it at all. I figure it is some kind of linking error but I don't have the experience to really figure this one out. If any other code would be useful please let me know! Thank you for any help you can provide!

EDIT:
I figured it out. So CAS_exec was calling the sensor.h file but it wasn't getting the paths to pcl and eigen3 with that compilation call. I added that and it works!

Comment: What errors are you getting, *exactly*? Also can you create a [mcve] that replicates the errors, and show it to us? And preferably, from a clean build (with all object and executable files removed) please show the full output from running `make`.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I was writing out a long edit with all the stuff you asked for but I fixed it. Thank you for your help even if it wasn't directly related! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just a question: why are you not using CMake but write your own Makefile? If you used CMake, you could easily avoid most of the issues you are facing.